# Is it possible to add hooks to the three main logical divisions in memoir?

Tags: memoir, hooks

I want to prepare a style based on memoir that executes code immediately before and after `frontmatter`, `mainmatter`, and `backmatter` (§6.1, pg.71). Without hooks, I have to insert the code in the Latex document, rather than the style file where it belongs. Should I use `renewcommand`?

For reference, the discussion on heading hooks is on page 353 of the memoir manual (§18.25)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? perhaps it is usuful for others?

Comment: @daleif: I set the page background color and PDF bookmark style in these three divisions differently to make them stand out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you want to add, there are some methods for appending and prepending to commands built into `memoir`. It provides a `\addtodef` command which (as its name implies) adds material to an existing macro.  It can also prepend things.  The syntax is (from p. 338 of the manual):

```
\addtodef{<macro>}{<prepend>}{<append>}
```

Depending on what it is you need to do, this may be the easiest route.  If it doesn't work, you can take the code from `memoir.cls` and redefine it within your package.

Comment: I've done exactly this to force a pagestyle change when the main matter starts, to force an `\appendixpage` right after a regular `\appendix` command, and check the page counts of the various "Lists of X" after each list has been typeset.